# asp:Button is not calling server-side function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm instantiating an asp:Button inside a data-bound asp:GridView through template fields. Some of the buttons are supposed to call a server-side function, but for some weird reason, it doesn't. All the buttons do when you click them is fire a postback to the current page, doing nothing, effectively just reloading the page.

Below is a fragment of the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="l2 submissions" ShowHeader="false">
    <Columns>      

        <asp:TemplateField>            
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Panel ID="swatchpanel" CssClass='<%# Bind("status") %>' runat="server"></asp:Panel></ItemTemplate>                
            <ItemStyle Width="50px" CssClass="sw" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" ReadOnly="true">                                
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="owner" ReadOnly="true">
            <ItemStyle Font-Italic="true" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="last-modified" ReadOnly="true">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="viewBtn" cssclass='<%# Bind("sid") %>' runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="viewBtnClick" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                         

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The viewBtn above should call the viewBtnClick() function on server-side. I do have that function defined, along with a proper signature (object,EventArgs). One thing that may be of note is that this code is actually inside an ASCX, which is loaded in another ASCX, finally loaded into an ASPX.

Any help or insight into the matter will be SO appreciated. Thanks!

(oh, and please don't mind my trashy HTML/CSS semantics - this is still in a very,very early stage :p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is AutoWireupEvents set to true?

Comment: yup, it most definitely is. :p

Comment: Is the child ascx this contains being dynamically added into the control tree at some point?

Comment: you might be on to something here. yup, you got that right. the ASCX is being loaded into the parent ASCX dynamically, based on a GET parameter.

Comment: for some reason, the controls' event handlers worked properly when the controls were instantiated during the ASCX's OnInit(), instead of on Page_Load(). 

I'm marking this as the answer 'cause this got me down the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your GridView is being databound during Page_Prerender, the asp:button in question doesn't exist when postback events are processed.

Try binding the gridview during Page_Load, or using the GridView's `OnItemCommand` event rather than the button's `OnClick`.

Comment: That's good insight, but my GridView is being databound during Page_Load already. I think I'll look into OnItemCommand as well though. Thanks for that!

However, I did try to take a regular asp:Button outside the GridView, and that too didn't fire its server-side hook. Weird.